# Is it possible to retain Hyperlinks from PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

```
  string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe";

  string inputFileName = Server.MapPath("pdf/myprofile.pdf");

  string outputFileName = @"D:\";

  string ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -o" + output + "-%d.jpg " + input;

    Process proc = new Process();

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;

    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;

    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    proc.Start();

    proc.WaitForExit();
```

I'm using asp.net application with c# language. I'm using the code above to convert the PDF to images using Ghost Script. Is it possible to retain Hyperlinks from PDF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFParser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET) to read the PDF as text (into a string) and then parse the string yourself for "http".
Just for completeness:

```
// create an instance of the pdfparser class
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();

// extract the text
String result = pdfParser.ExtractText(pdfFile);
if(result.ToLower().Contains("http"))
{
//split the string on known factors like a "\n" and "/" for ending the url. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm uploading the converted images to the Flip book. Now, once I got the hyperlink from the PDF, how to again assign it to the image, so that it must be click-able in Flip book?

Comment: @Pearl Normally Stackoverflow's policy is to ask this in another question. Well basic HTML knowledge would say: `<a href="linkYouFound">
<img src="imgSource.jpg"></a>`

Comment: @user2754599the code u provided will redirects to a page when u click on the image. But, I want to redirect to the page when click on Hyperlink only.